# lsof indicates that my java process is leaking /devices/pseudo/tl@0:ticots

Tags: java, jboss, memory-leaks, file-descriptor, lsof

I have a java EE app running in Jboss in Unix and I have noticed that after a couple of days I get "too many open files"
I've identified what is leaking but I have no idea what it actually is or how to find which part of my code that is leaking

my analysis of lsof shows that these rows are slowly increasing:

```
java    25222  user  220u  unix    105,208835    0t465959  55050244 /devices/pseudo/tl@0:ticots->(socketpair: 0x32fc3) (0x6009c7d41f0)
```

the closest thing to a similar problem is http://tinyurl.com/csmy7ay
I use JMS so the problem might lie there.

But my main question is how should I proceed in my quest to fix this? I'm having a hard time finding anything tangible in the lsof file that might help me determine what kind of traffic this is and where in my code they might be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was, there was a maintenance script running which, among other things, ran jstack which together with this bug: http://tinyurl.com/c5fdl43 (java attach API in solaris causes too make open files). Caused the file leak

Comment: had exact same issue under tomcat 6u32, thanks for posting your find, will be trying 6u65 to fix as the bug indicates it is fixed